# I want to eliminate the blank area under the container in bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to expand the `box_switch` (red frame part) part of the image below to Top
and apply background color.

[image]

React.js

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="row mx-auto text-center">
      <>
          <div className="col-12">
            <div className="box_switch">
                <img className="" src={plugon_pic} />
              <p className="under_ic_switch_state">{item.state}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.css

```
.box_switch {
    position: relative;
    background:#1E3E75; 
    padding:15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: ０ calc(50% - 50vw) 15px;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```css
.box_switch {
  position: relative;
  background: #1E3E75;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: ０ calc(50% - 50vw) 15px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="box_switch">
        <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
        <p class="under_ic_switch_state">{item.state}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure it is not because you have margin?

Comment: oh yes I changed margin: ０ calc(50% - 50vw) 15px; but same result...

Comment: I've added a snippet demo with your code. Does it show the problem?

Comment: Bootstrap containers don't have top margin. Have you inspected the document to see what element or class does? This may just be a matter of default body padding. At any rate, there's not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Thank you .container {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
} works

Answer (score 0):

then i think this will do

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .box_switch {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  
    background:#1E3E75; 
    padding:15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: ０ calc(50% - 50vw) 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: you can remove the position absolute or change it if you want it wont effect the result. You are also having an overflow because of your 100% width and padding, so i recommend using box-sizing:border-box

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
.container {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```